# Retrieving "Number" From Sql VB.NET System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

If I want to retrieve a value that is saved as a number in an access database.

Im using the following:

```
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT ArithmeticScore FROM " & tablename & " WHERE DateAscending = '" & todaysdate & "'"
            Using connection As New OleDbConnection(getconn)
                Using command As New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)
                    connection.Open()
                    scorevalue = CDec(command.ExecuteScalar()) 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
                    connection.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
            MsgBox(scorevalue)
```

`getconn` = connection string as a string

`scorevalue` = Nothing as decimal

The field `ArithmeticScore` is set to `Number` in the table.

The exact value in the cell right now is `50`, but the program should allow for any decimal value.

The error im getting is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

Comment: Yikes, this looks vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: What is the database and what is the data type of the `DateAscending` column? If it's SQL Server then you really ought to be using `SqlClient` rather than `OleDb`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I googled the exact text of the error message, seems to indicate Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `criteria expression` mentioned in the error message does not refer to the `ArithmeticScore` output. It's talking about the `WHERE` clause. Whatever you have for `todaysdate` does not match what the database is expecting for the `DateAscending` column.

Since OleDb is a generic provider, we don't know exactly what kind of database you're talking to, but most databases have a way to get the current date value in SQL: `getdate()`, `current_timestamp`, etc. Using that mechanism will likely solve the conflict, and there's no need to use string concatenation for this in the first place.

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT ArithmeticScore FROM " & tablename & " WHERE DateAscending = Date()"
```

The other way you can fix this is with proper **parameterized queries**, which you should doing anyway. It's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to substitute data into an SQL query, and if you find yourself needing to think about how to format a date or number string for use in an SQL command, you're almost always doing something very wrong.

Comment: So there is no record in the database where todaysdate is present in DateAscending?

Comment: No. If there were no record, you'd see a different message. This is saying the format of the `todaysdate` value is not correct for comparing with `DateAscending`.

Comment: I have written the date in the variable `todaysdate` to `DateAscending` without an issue multiple times in the program, is the data type treated differently when writing and reading?